# Dividing two querys in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to divide two querys in PostgreSQL:

My sample data is :

```
time                          coil_id    pushing_force  drawing_force

"2017-08-15 23:03:23.1"          0        855.125          0   
"2017-08-15 23:03:23.11"         0        822.12           0
"2017-08-15 23:03:23.12"         0         0              771.572
"2017-08-15 23:03:23.13"         0         0              772.572
"2017-08-15 23:03:23.14"         1        899.92           0
"2017-08-15 23:03:23.15"         1        821.12           0
"2017-08-15 23:03:23.16"         1         0              742.15
"2017-08-15 23:03:23.17"         2        892.1            0
"2017-08-15 23:03:23.18"         2         0              775.528
"2017-08-15 23:03:23.19"         2         0              771.572
"2017-08-15 23:03:23.2"          3        955.52           0
"2017-08-15 23:03:23.21"         3         0              768.866
"2017-08-15 23:03:23.22"         3         0              765.866
```

My first query is:

```
SELECT avg(d1.pushing_force)*0.1
  FROM drawing d1, (
       SELECT coil_id, max(drawing_force) as mdrawing_force
         FROM drawing
        GROUP BY coil_id
       ) d2 
 WHERE d1.pushing_force > d2.mdrawing_force
   AND d1.coil_id = d2.coil_id
GROUP BY d1.coil_id
ORDER BY d1.coil_id
```

output:

```
96.0686237179488
98.2271765407554
98.3511043388427
99.0244
99.782412195122
98.9033064593301
```

My second query is :

```
SELECT AVG(drawing_force)*0.1 from drawing group by coil_id order by coil_id
```

output :

```
67.4467013876606
34.7058347285139
45.304114594917
36.9346255571282
33.4687833398917
24.9778648102293
30.40511668208
```

I want to divide query1/query2 to see the output

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: @jarlh Postgrsql

Comment: The error message says it all, you have a subquery (or two) that returns more than one row. You can't really do "a bunch of values" divided by "a bunch of values".

Comment: @jarlh yes , So I am not able to figure out the answer. But there is group by is same . I aslo try to use join

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. ([mcve])

Comment: @Nitesh, add some sample data and your expected output in tabular format, from your question it is not clear what you want to do

Comment: @Fahmi , i hope I am clear about my question

Comment: Your queries have no output column which allows to understand what row from 1st rowset on what row from 2nd rowset must be divided. Add column(s) needed for correct matching determining into the outputs.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Why are you choosing to use archaic SQL syntax instead of proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?  I would advise you to ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: The specified result can't possibly match the sample data. (There are only 4 different coil_id's, you do GROUP BY coil_id, and get 7 rows back - no way!)

Comment: You said Postgresql, don't add the MySQL tag!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you well, you want to join result of both queries into one and you want to divide average of `pushing_force` by average of `drawing_force` to get result for each  `coil_id`.

Try this:

```
SELECT  t1.coil_id, t1.avg_pushingforce, t2.avg_drawing_force, t1.avg_pushingforce/t2.avg_drawing_force as result
FROM 
(
    SELECT coil_id, avg(d1.pushing_force)*0.1 as avg_pushingforce
    FROM drawing d1
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT coil_id, max(drawing_force) as mdrawing_force
            FROM drawing
            GROUP BY coil_id
        ) d2 ON d1.pushing_force > d2.mdrawing_force AND d1.coil_id = d2.coil_id
    GROUP BY d1.coil_id
) t1 INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT coil_id, avg(drawing_force)*0.1 as avg_drawing_force 
        FROM drawing
        GROUP BY coil_id
    ) t2 ON t1.coil_id = t2.coil_id
ORDER BY t1.coil_id
```

**Note:** i'm using `join` instead of joining tables in `where` clause. See: [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: @Machiej Los you understood the question very well. I tried your code but got am error:ERROR: ERROR: Column "d2.avg_drawing_force" must appear in the GROUP-BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT (avg(d1.pushing_force)*0.1)/avg_drawing_force as resu...

Comment: So, add this field to `GROUP BY` clause ;)

Comment: @Machiej Los the code has executed successfully but i think the result are not currect as   you will see in my ques tion the divission is done on basis of only group by coil_id but here we used GROUP BY d1.coil_id, d2.avg_drawing_force. example from my question : 97.068/67.44

Comment: @Machiej Los ERROR: ERROR: Column reference "coil_id" is not unique
LINE 4: SELECT coil_id, avg (d1.pushing_force) * 0.1 as avg_pushing ...
                   ^

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this query

```
with cte as (
    SELECT dr.coil_id, max(dr.drawing_force) as mdrawing_force
         FROM drawing dr
        GROUP BY dr.coil_id
)
SELECT (case when sum(case when d1.pushing_force > d2.mdrawing_force then 1 else 0 end) > 0 
              then sum(case when d1.pushing_force > d2.mdrawing_force then d1.pushing_force else 0 end)
                 / sum(case when d1.pushing_force > d2.mdrawing_force then 1 else 0 end)
              else 0 -- to avoid divide by zero error
              end)
         / avg(d1.pushing_force)*0.1
  FROM drawing d1
  inner join cte d2 using (coil_id)
  GROUP BY d1.coil_id
  ORDER BY d1.coil_id
```